# How to show or hide ion-icon when no internet connection in ion navbar?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to show or hide ion-icon when checking for internet connectivity? I'm a little confused about that, so if you know how to resolve this let me see. Thanks
I've been set this in HTML ngIf function:

```
<ion-buttons end>
      <div >
        <ion-icon name="ios-wifi" style="zoom:1.5;" *ngIf="!wifi"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </ion-buttons>
```

Here is a ts of my network provider and where to check for it. Thanks a lot for a little support and help.
network.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export enum ConnectionStatus {
  Online,
  Offline
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkService {

  private status: BehaviorSubject<ConnectionStatus> = new BehaviorSubject(ConnectionStatus.Offline);

  constructor(private network: Network, private toastController: ToastController, private plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {

      this.initializeNetworkEvents();
      let status = this.network.type !== 'none' ? ConnectionStatus.Online : ConnectionStatus.Offline;
      this.status.next(status);
    });
  }

  public initializeNetworkEvents() {

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
        console.log('OFFLINE');
        this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Offline);
      }
    });

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
        console.log('ONLINE');
        this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Online);
      }
    });
  }

  private async updateNetworkStatus(status: ConnectionStatus) {
    this.status.next(status);

    let connection = status == ConnectionStatus.Offline ? 'Internet konekcija prekinuta.' : 'Konekcija uspostavljena';

    this.toastController.create({
      message: `${connection}`,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
    }).present();
  };

  public onNetworkChange(): Observable<ConnectionStatus> {
    return this.status.asObservable();
  }

  public getCurrentNetworkStatus(): ConnectionStatus {
    return this.status.getValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using network plugin?? Please Share code

Comment: Yes, i'm using network plugin and network provider and I want to show or hide this ion icon on every form i have. I will share network provider ts below.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib check now. thanks

Comment: I tried a millions way to display ionicons offline, it's just a pain. Rather use Font Awesome

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

in your app.component.ts

```
    import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
    import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';

        constructor(private network: Network, public events: Events,) {
          // watch network for a disconnection
          let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {

           console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
           this.events.publish('networkStatus', {status: false}); 
          });

    // watch network for a connection    
    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');
      this.events.publish('networkStatus', {status: true});
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
          console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
        }
      }, 3000);
    });

 }
```

inside your page.ts

```
constructor(){
   this.events.subscribe('networkStatus', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if(data.status == false){
        this.wifi = false;
      }else{
        this.wifi = true;
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Everything is the same. Ion-icon is not visible and still doesn't work.

Comment: try like this: 
`<ion-icon name="ios-wifi" style="zoom:1.5;" *ngIf="wifi == true"></ion-icon>`.

Comment: Ion-icon is still there even true or false.